# Obtaining accessToken for google sign-in (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin

I'm using Google sign-in in my application

the problem is that I want to obtain `accessToken` to send it to the back end server, but the `GoogleSignInAccount` dosen't have it

```
private fun handleGoogleSignInResult(task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {

    task.addOnSuccessListener { googleSignInAccount ->

        // TODO: Obtaining accessToken

    }

    task.addOnFailureListener { e ->
        Timber.e(e)
        showToast(R.string.something_went_wrong_try_again_later)
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients

Comment: no, I need the accessToken that I can send to back-end server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you might have to cast the `AuthCredential` to `OAuthCredential` to get the `accessToken`. Try the below. Note, I did not run this code to verify. Some additional information here: [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin#authenticate_with_firebase)

```
private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String) {
        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
        val auth = Firebase.auth
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    val user = auth.currentUser
                    val oAuthCredential = credential as OAuthCredential
                    val token = oAuthCredential.accessToken
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                }
            }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
The above fails as casting fails.

Seems like the Android SDK does not provide an easy way to get the access code.

Have a look at this link for another option: [GoogleAuthUtil](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil#getToken(android.content.Context,%20android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle))
Beware of some of the info mentioned in the link like running this async etc.
You might be able to get the access token so:

```
val scope = "oauth2:" + Scopes.EMAIL + " " + Scopes.PROFILE;
                    val account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)
                    val token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(this, account?.account, scope)
```

Comment: This code throw java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthCredential cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.auth.OAuthCredential

Comment: Alright, that was partly expected. One last try:        `auth.getAccessToken(false).addOnSuccessListener {it.token.}`

Comment: works but provie another access token doesn't start with "ya29."

Comment: server access token should start with "ya29."

Comment: Updated my answer. You would have to try it out though.